# What is the difference between "Continuation Stealing" and "Child Stealing"?

Tags: multithreading, scheduling

A [section of the Wikipedia page about the "Work Stealing" scheduling strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_stealing#Child_stealing_vs._continuation_stealing)
(in the context of parallel computing) mentions variants of the algorithm.

With "Continuation stealing":

> the continuation of the function [that was executed by the parent thread] can be stolen while the spawned thread is executed [by the parent thread that spawned it]

it is then added in the same section:

> the alternative strategy is called "Child Stealing"

however, there is no description of how it differs from "Continuation Stealing".

What is the difference when a scheduling strategy does "Child Stealing"?

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I would recommend reading chapter 6 of the book "Concurrency in Go".

Let me tell you briefly with example.

Let's say we have two processes of P1, P2
Parent Thread runs on P1, then child Thread is invoked by the parent
- Now we have two jobs to do. one is left of the parent, the other is a child thread.

1) Child stealing
- P1 keeps executing the parent thread which is below the child invoking code
- and put the child thread to the P1's scheduler (kind of todo list?)
- now P2 has nothing to do and checked other Process's scheduler (or job queue?) 
- and sees the child thread. **P1 steals the child** and executes child.

2) Continuation stealing
- P1 keeps executing the parent thread which is below the child invoking code
- and **P1 executes the child thread!** and put the left of the parent thread to the P1's job queue. let's say it as a continuation of the parent thread
- P2 sees continuations on P1's queue, and **P1 steals the continuation** and executes continuation.

I'll not say the reason. but continuation stealing is better than the child stealing.
and continuation stealing need support from the compiler

Comment: Shouldn't it be `P2 steals the child and executes child.` for child stealing?

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from *"[Nowa: A Wait-Free Continuation-Stealing Concurrency Platform](https://www4.cs.fau.de/Publications/2021/schmaus2021nowa.pdf)"*:

> **B. Child-Stealing versus Continuation-Stealing**
>
> One of the most important aspects of a concurrency platform is the employed work-stealing scheme [11]. It can be either child-stealing or continuation-stealing (Figure 3), and influences, among other things, the order in which tasks are executed.
>
> In *child-stealing*, a spawning function makes its child tasks available to be stolen. The example in Figure 3b shows that, at the fork point, W1 pushes its child task τ c into its work-stealing queue and continues executing τ p. This allows W2 to steal the child task τ c from W1. While this scheme is very intuitive, it has multiple drawbacks. First, due to the potentially large amount of child tasks, those may need to be dynamically allocated. Hence the runtime system inherits the performance characteristics of the dynamic memory allocator, which often employs locks. Secondly, child-stealing tends to cause more frequent stack switches, which are expensive.
>
> With *continuation-stealing*, the runtime system offers the continuation after the spawned child task to thieves. While this may appear as a subtle change, it has a strong impact. Most notably, if the continuation is not stolen, which is the typical case, the worker can proceed without a stack switch (Figure 3c). Furthermore, since, in fully-strict continuation-stealing, there is only at most one pending continuation per spawning function, the storage for the continuation instance can be allocated on the stack without requiring the dynamic memory allocator. Figure 1 shows an example where a platform that employs child-stealing, TBB, performs much worse than the continuation-stealing ones.

**Reference:** F. Schmaus, N. Pfeiffer, T. Hönig, J. Nolte and W. Schröder-Preikschat, "Nowa: A Wait-Free Continuation-Stealing Concurrency Platform," 2021 IEEE International Parallel and Distributed Processing Symposium (IPDPS), Portland, OR, USA, 2021, pp. 360-371, doi: 10.1109/IPDPS49936.2021.00044.